# Как расположить Alert в углу экрана

Tags: java, javafx, alert

хочу чтобы было вот так, но не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
        alert.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!");
        alert.setY(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height -alert.getHeight())
        alert.setX(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width-alert.getWidth());
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Каков фактический результат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут проблема заключается в `alert.getHeight()` и `alert.getWidth()`. Эти функции возвращают `NaN`. Для того чтобы получить реальные размеры надо сначала показать этот диалог потом изменить позицию.

```
package alert;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainAlert extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    private StackPane createContent() {

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        Button showAlert = new Button("Show me alert dialog");
        showAlert.setOnAction(event -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!");
            Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

            alert.show();
            alert.setX(bounds.getMaxX() - alert.getWidth() - 10);
            alert.setY(bounds.getMaxY() - alert.getHeight() - 10);
        });

        stackPane.getChildren().add(showAlert);
        return stackPane;
    }
}
```

Но во время показа есть блик. К сожалению по другому не получается. Поэтому я Вам советую создать собственный диалог с точным размером, чтобы можно было задавать точную позицию. В моем случае размер диалога 360 х 174.

Например, так:

```
int indent = 10; // 10 pixels
alert.setX(bounds.getMaxX() - 360 - indent);
alert.setY(bounds.getMaxY() - 174 - indent);
alert.show();
```